# How to use return redirect in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, return

```
public function getleaveType(Request $request){
        $leave_types = leaveType::all();

        //create leave-type
        if($request->isMethod('POST')){
            $leave_Type = new leaveType;
            $leave_Type->leave_type = $request->input('leaveType');
            $leave_Type->staff_type = $request->input('staffType');
            $leave_Type->leave_days = $request->input('leaveDays');
            $leave_Type->leave_description = $request->input('leaveDescription');
            $leave_Type->save();
        }

        return redirect('leave/leaveType', ['leave_t' => $leave_types]);
    }
```

Comment: Have been trying to use return redirect but its not reloding the page as expected. the error message i get is The "HTTP status code "1" is not valid".

Comment: the second argument to `redirect` is the status (integer) .. what are you trying to do by passing that array? also why is this single method handling multiple HTTP methods?

Comment: the leave/leaveType is the page i want to redirect to WHILE the ['leave_t' => $leave_types] is to display some information fetched from the database on a table

Comment: where ever you redirect to should be handling that data ... provide the code of where ever you are trying to redirect to then

Comment: First check what are you getting in `$leave_types`?

Comment: Am really confused to because am new with laravel and stackoverflow let me just show you the code for the blade file


is there a way i can show you the blade file?

Comment: i am trying to redirect to laravel/leaveType which is the blade file. i used the if and foreach to fetch the date from the database @lagbox

Comment: you dont redirect to blade files, you redirect to a route

Comment: @prashant i am getting the data in the model leaveType

Comment: the issue is if i use return view, its working but whenever i add a new data into the database it wont show that data until i have to reload

Comment: @lagbox Please how do i redirect to a route

Comment: obviously you have to reload to fetch newly added data in db

Comment: because you are fetching all the records for that table before you are adding the new record (the result set doesn't contain anything you add after you fetch it), you would need to fetch the records after you add the new record to your table

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are passing data `$leave_types` to `route` and not to `view`.

It should be something like this

```
 return view('view_name', ['leave_t' => $leave_types]);
```

OR

```
 return view('view_name')->with('leave_t',$leave_types);
```

Edit:

Try this

```
    public function getleaveType(Request $request){

    //create leave-type
    if($request->isMethod('POST')){
        $leave_Type = new leaveType;
        $leave_Type->leave_type = $request->input('leaveType');
        $leave_Type->staff_type = $request->input('staffType');
        $leave_Type->leave_days = $request->input('leaveDays');
        $leave_Type->leave_description = $request->input('leaveDescription');
        $leave_Type->save();
    }
    $leave_types = leaveType::all();
    return view('view_name')->with('leave_t',$leave_types);
}
```

Comment: please explain the changes you made and why you have made those changes, instead of only saying "try this", thanks

Comment: @lagbox I have fetched `leaveType` at the end after `save()`, so it will fetch newly added records.

Comment: its not for me, add it to the answer

Comment: have tried this and its worked but when i add a new data into the table it does not display the last data Until i reload the page

Comment: and this is exactly why you have to point out in the answer what changes you made and why

Comment: The code worked 

public function getleaveType(Request $request){

    //create leave-type
    if($request->isMethod('POST')){
        $leave_Type = new leaveType;
        $leave_Type->leave_type = $request->input('leaveType');
        $leave_Type->staff_type = $request->input('staffType');
        $leave_Type->leave_days = $request->input('leaveDays');
        $leave_Type->leave_description = $request->input('leaveDescription');
        $leave_Type->save();
    }
    $leave_types = leaveType::all();
    return view('view_name')->with('leave_t',$leave_types);
}

Thanks Alot

Answer (score 1):

```
return redirect()->route('leave/leaveType')->with( ['leave_t' => $leave_types]);
```

Try to use redirect like above and encapsulate the values you want to pass using `with` function